# Find words in array and get their indexes in Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'token_1': [['cat', 'run','today'],['dog', 'eat', 'meat']],
        'token_2': [[ 'in', 'the' , 'morning','cat', 'run', 'today',
                      'very', 'quick'],['dog', 'eat', 'meat', 'chicken', 'from', 'bowl']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to find words from column `token_1` in `token_2` and get their indixes in an array.
Then get a list of indexes for each line, i expected this:

```
lst_indexes = [[3,4,5],
                [0,1,2]]
```

Comment: Be aware that you picked a quadratic solution! if you have large list, this will become quite slower, for example for ~2k items this is a few hundred times slower than my solution with a dictionary ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `enumerate` for indices:

```
L = [[i for i, x in enumerate(b) if x in a] for a, b in zip(df['token_1'], df['token_2'])]
print (L)
[[3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary/list comprehension:

```
# first compute a dictionary of indices for efficiency
indices = [{w: i for i,w in enumerate(l)} for l in df['token_2']]

# then map the indices
[[d.get(x,None) for x in l] for d, l in zip(indices, df['token_1'])]
```

output:

```
[[3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse `data` dictionary and append values to a new list:

```
data = {'token_1': [['cat', 'run','today'],['dog', 'eat', 'meat']],
        'token_2': [[ 'in', 'the' , 'morning','cat', 'run', 'today',
                      'very', 'quick'],['dog', 'eat', 'meat', 'chicken', 'from', 'bowl']]}

l = []
for i in range(len(data["token_1"])):
    l.append([])
    for j in range(len(data["token_1"][i])):
        a = data["token_2"][i].index(data["token_1"][i][j])
        if a!=-1:
            l[i].append(a)
print(l)
```

*Note that the other solutions look much more clear and readable, this is only an alternative to list comprehension*

**Output:**

```
[[3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]]
```